# when we are testing the test case in "selenium" nUnit, the tests are passing in debugging mode

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017, nunit

when we are testing the test case in "selenium" nUnit, the tests are passing in debugging mode i.e while pressing F10 but it was failing when we are running tests

```
    [Test, Category("CRMAccounts")]
    public void TheNewTest()
    {
        Utils.ClickOnApplicationCategory(driver, "CRM");
        Utils.ClickOnApplication(driver, "Accounts");
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("aframe");
        Utils.ClickButtonBar(driver, "New");
        // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | null | ]]

        // Thread.Sleep(1000); if i keep this  in between the code test is passing but  I dont want to give this for every // line 

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[2]/input[@type='text']")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[2]/input[@type='text']")).SendKeys("029");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[4]/input[@type='text']")).Clear();

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[4]/input[@type='text']")).SendKeys("Account 1");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"main_field208\"]")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"main_field208\"]")).SendKeys("Account SN");
        driver.FindElement(
            By.XPath("//form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/input")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[5]/td[2]/input[@type='text']")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[5]/td[2]/input[@type='text']")).SendKeys("www.test.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[5]/td[4]/input[@type='text']")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[5]/td[4]/input[@type='text']")).SendKeys("sk@live.co.uk");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[6]/td[2]/input[@type='text']")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[6]/td[2]/input[@type='text']")).SendKeys("040-1234567");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]/input")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[4]/input"))
            .SendKeys("040-123456789");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSave_input")).Click();
        // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | null | ]]
        driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("aframe");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span/span")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("grdData_grdMeta_ctl00_ctl04_hypEdit")).Click();
        // PostCondition
        // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | null | ]]
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnDelete_input")).Click();
        Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(CloseAlertAndGetItsText(),
            "^All items related to this account will be DELETED and cannot be recovered\\. Delete this Account[\\s\\S]$"));
        driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
        driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
        driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
        driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
    }
```

setup and teardown are working fine
If i add thread.sleep(1000);it is working or else if i use de bugging mobe and if i use F10 key and debugging it is fine but i am geting issues only whwn i am runing the test

Comment: Can you share some code? It's really hard to provide you with an answer without more details

Comment: I added (nunit) code

Comment: It is very hard to understand what your tests are doing without seeing your web page, but it looks like you are not waiting for the result of clicking the new button to complete, so the page is not loaded and the DOM is not updated when you start finding elements. You need to await the page load or DOM changing.